# Python com acces denied

Tags: python, serial-port, thermal-printer

i am trying to use POSSIFY FY825X printer and accesing to it but it gives me com access denied error
all i am doing is

```
from escpos.printer import Serial
p = Serial("COM11")
p.open()
```

and gives me

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM11': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

pls help
i am using it but i cant control

i tried any software that i can use it and it worked so nothing wrong with printer
i tried to run code and use another software at same time software gave busy error so i can open the COM but i cant use it